# Cannot get value from second field from search result using ElasticSearch in Flutter

Tags: flutter, elasticsearch

My Json data looks as follows:

```
{
  "foodName" : "Pineapple",
  "brandName": "Fruit Inc."
}
```

and for the longest time I've tried to display a ListTile with both the "foodName" and the "brandName" but I can only get the "foodName" to show.

I tried creating a different class called "Food" with these 2 values and using "Food.fromJson(currDoc)" and below that then I was able to map the values, but I was only able to print it to the console, I couldn't get it to show in the ListTile.

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:elastic_client/elastic_client.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:elastic_client/elastic_client.dart' as elastic;

class ElasticSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () async {
          query = '';
          await searchElasticServer(query);
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  Future searchElasticServer(searchQuery) async {
    final transport = HttpTransport(
      url: 'ELASTIC_SEARCH_ENDPOINT_URL',
      authorization: basicAuthorization("ELASTIC_SEARCH_USERNAME", "ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD"));
    final client = elastic.Client(transport);

    List<String> foodsList = List();

    final searchResult = await client.search(
        index: 'foods', 
        type: '_doc', 
        query: elastic.Query.term('foodName', ['$searchQuery']),
        source: true);

    print("----------- Found ${searchResult.totalCount} $searchQuery ----------");

    for(final iter in searchResult.hits){
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> currDoc = iter.doc;

      foodsList.add(
        currDoc['foodName'].toString(),
        );
    }

    await transport.close();

    if(searchResult.totalCount <= 0 )
      return null;
    else
      return foodsList;
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: searchElasticServer(query),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Center(child: Text("No results"));

        return  _displayFoodResult(snapshot.data) ;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: searchElasticServer(query),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text("No results");

        return _displayFoodResult(snapshot.data) ;
      },
    );
  }


  Widget _displayFoodResult( List<String> foodList) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: foodList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(foodList[index]),
        );
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Does anyone know how I could map both field values to a ListTile?

```
ListTile(
   title: Text(foodName),
   subtitle: Text(brandName),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally get it by creating a model class and making a few changes:

class:

```
class Food {
  final String foodName;
  final String brandName;

  Food(this.foodName, this.brandName);
  
}
```

Now with this class created, I was able to do the following changes to get it to work:

```
(-) List<String> foodsList = List();
(+) List<Food> foodsList = List();
```

```
(-) foodsList.add(currDoc['foodName'].toString());
(+) foodsList.add(Food(currDoc['foodName'], currDoc['brandName']));
```

```
(-) Widget _displayFoodResult( List<String> foodList) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: foodList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(foodList[index]),
        );
      }
    );
  }
(+) Widget _displayFoodResult( List<Food> foodList) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: foodList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(foodList[index].foodName),
          subtitle: Text(foodList[index].brandName),
        );
      }
    );
  }
```